# Html and css why do divs effect each other?

Tags: html, css

Hello my English is not good. I am making a website with html and css and have encountered a problem. I will show you code first and then show questions.

html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html lange="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

   <link REL=StyleSheet HREF="css/style.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>

  <title>Space and Tech</title> 

  <body>

 <div id = "header"></div>

 <div id = "logo">
 <img src="img/ghost.png" id = "ghost">
 <img src="img/apparition.png" id = "apperition">
 </div>

  <!---<a  href="about.html" id = "Link1"> our HTML tutorial</a>-->
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
  body{

background: #CCAC7E;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica","Arial"; 

  }

 #header{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #F97139;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
 }

  #logo{

   width: 75px;
   height: 75px;
   margin-top: -88px;
   margin-left: 50px;
 }

#apperition{

 margin-top: -128px;
 margin-left: 90px;
  }
```

The problem is when I change the margin of say #header it moves and so does #apparition and #logo. I am not sure why this happens but could anyone help me please!

Comment: The reason they affect each other is that style sheets "cascade".  In your case, you need to make sure your positions are set "relative", "fixed", or "absolute" depending on how you wish them to interact with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to what durbnpoisn already wrote, the default the position (the one preset for which you dont have to code or need to code) is static.
Here are all the posible positions: static|absolute|fixed|relative|initial|inherit;

Explanation for each:

static=>Elements render in order, as they appear in the document flow.

absolute=>The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

fixed=>The element is positioned relative to the browser window.

relative=>The element is positioned relative to its normal position, so "left:20" adds 20 pixels to the element's LEFT position.

initial=>Sets this property to its default value.

inherit=>Inherits this property from its parent element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a veteran developer at all, but I'll take a stab at this one.

The position property should fix your issues. Try setting your background div with a position property of **position:absolute;** with some margin padding around all sides.

Then, try setting your other divs with a position property of **position:relative;**

However, your other divs with the relative positioning will not be affected yet. after you set them to relative, give them some exact positions such as "top", "bottom", "left", and right" based on where you want them.